# Does the rent for the 'Double the rent' card need to be paid in two steps?

Tags: monopoly-deal

If I have played the rent card + the double the rent card, do the other players need to pay me for the total doubled amount or do they have to pay it in two steps?

Example:
I play Rent card (6m) + double the rent.
Now they need to to pay 6m + 6m or 12m?

Answer (score 4):

The double the rent card has to be played with a rent card, and doubles the rent to be payed for that rent card. 
In your example, they would need to pay just 12m.