# Monopoly deal - double the rent

Tags: monopoly-deal

I have a full blue property set and ask the rent (8million) and play a double the rent card, which would make it 16 million in total.

Do they have to pay me 2 x 8 million or 1 x 16 million?

Arguments made by us were: it are two separate cards, so payments should be separate. **or** the cards should be played simultaneously, so the payment is combined in one.

Which is correct?

Comment: This is not a monopoly I am familiar with. Care to clarify?

Comment: Monopoly deal. the card Game. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.com/Hasbro-B0965-Monopoly-Deal-Card/dp/B00NQQTZCO&ved=2ahUKEwjwkrSnjM_oAhWK16QKHUbFCRYQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0IQgtiQ9jeV6J5jdQg2fCk

Comment: What's the difference? Either way they have to pay 16 mil.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the rent for the 'Double the rent' card need to be paid in two steps?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49777/does-the-rent-for-the-double-the-rent-card-need-to-be-paid-in-two-steps)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the rules [here](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=instructionbook#top) the rules clarification for Double the Rent says (emphasis mine)

> Play **with** a standard rent card to double the amount

The FAQ link to [here](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=rent#question-rent-2) it says

> 2. Does the Double The Rent card count as a turn? Does it count as one of your three plays? Yes. An example would be a player lays a property
>      card, a rent card, and a double the rent card during their turn. This
>      would be all three of their card plays.

So based on that i would says that 'Double the rent' is playing **with** (ie simultaneously) with the rent card.  The payment is 1 x 16 million lump sum because 'Double the Rent' and 'Rent' are played at exactly the same time.

I'm confused as to why asking for 16 million once over 8 million twice makes a difference as I've only played this once many years ago under duress and just checked the rules to answer this.

Comment: In my eyes: Playing card with, only implies that otherwise it is useless. Normally it wouldn't matter but really matter but if no change is given for excess payments, it mattered a lot in this case

Comment: If no change is given then yes I see why it might make a difference now.  I still stand by argument reasoning that you play WITH.  also that card says double THE rent.  there is only one rent still.  It doesn't say charge rent again.

Comment: I like that reasoning. "THE" rent is singular. It's doubled.

Comment: Agree, always assumed this was the amount of the (single) rent was doubled, not "two rents".

Comment: According to card description, the **amount** is doubled. No words about separate payments.